# How to generate code samples from a grammar?

Tags: parsing, grammar

I have access to a grammar, and want to use it to generate code samples that follow the grammar.

Is there some existing tool that does this? If not, what is the right approach?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try [mutt](http://www.schneertz.com/rmutt/) or some of the tools [listed here](http://www.quiveringbrain.com/TextGenerators.html) might do what you are looking for.

If you wanted to implement a text generator yourself, you could randomly select a possible expansion of the current symbol and go down the path until you cannot any more or reached a limit, then try to select a terminator symbol if available